# Getting useful STL debugging in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I'm using XCode for some iOS development and the watch window for viewing STL is almost worthless by default. In Visual Studio I could edit the autoexp.dat file to make STL viewing more useful, is there any way to do something similar in XCode? I'd also like to do this same treatment with XCode for Boost libraries if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Apple has finally decided to give C++ some attention. As of XCode 4.5 debugging and the watch window will be vastly improved and should be able to display STL types easily. Apple is deprecating GCC support, only through the use of LLVM4 will you be able to get the new debugging features, as well as C++11 support.

As of the time of writing this XCode 4.5 is in Beta and is only accessible to registered Apple developers. Here's a link to the XCode download page, which contains a link to XCode 4.5 for registered developers only. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: It's 2018 now and using STL with XCode still sucks.  :-(